# Incorrect values on pandas dataframe after applying lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to replace single quote values in dataframe with \' before it gets inserted to a table.

```
Out[23]:2 ABC
        3 DEF
        4 NaN
```

After applying lambda to replace single quotes,

`df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("'", "\'"))`

Result:

```
Out[25]:2 NaN
        3 Nan
        4 NaN
```

Please advise what is going wrong here.

Comment: Can you confirm what `df` contains? `out[23]` does not have single quotes, so I am confused.

Comment: There are other columns in the df that could contain values like "didn't", "It'd". Before inserting to a table, I want to make them "didn\\'t" and "it\\'d" so that it will be treated as escape characters before inserting to table. When i apply the above lambda, for some reason, even values like ABC and DEF end up becoming NaN